# how to save beep sound To audio file in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code using beep sound , I want to make it as audio file like MP3 , WMA ... , Anyone Can Help Me ?

This is My code

Module :

```
Public Declare Function Beep Lib "kernel32" _
   (ByVal dwFreq As Long, _
    ByVal dwDuration As Long) As Long
```

Main Code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Set ws = ActiveSheet
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

tempo = 500 '0.5 sec

For I = 1 To LR

HB = ws.Range("B" & I).Value
L = ws.Range("C" & I).Value

Beep HB, L

Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: So you want a specific song instead of `Beep`?

Comment: Using VBA for audio synthesis seems like a square peg in a round hole to me.

Comment: Ya is a Birthday song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you play some specific `*.wav` sound from VBA something like this should be quite ok:

```
Option Explicit

Public Declare Function sndPlaySound32 Lib "winmm.dll" _
       Alias "sndPlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszSoundName As String, _
       ByVal uFlags As Long) As Long

Sub VBASound()
    Application.EnableSound = True
    sndPlaySound32 ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\LoadIt.WAV", 0
End Sub
```

[*Credits to these guys.*](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?8793-System-beep)